# Plotting numeric y-value data with non-numeric x-values in R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Let's say I have data looking like this:

```
type    value
A        1
A        1
A        2
A        2
A        3
B        2
B        2
B        2
B        3
C        2
C        3
C        4
C        5
```

How can I plot this in one graph, so I have the A, B, and C types on the x-axis, and then the corresponding y-values for each type plotted as dots?
So kind of a scatter plot, but with fixed x-values.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ggplot2. It automatically identifies categorical variables and treats them accordingly.

```
library(ggplot)
#say your dataframe is stored as data
ggplot(aes(x=data$type,y=data$value))+geom_point()
```

As Ian points out, this will indeed over plot.  You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255781/what-is-difference-between-geom-point-and-geom-jitter-in-simple-language-in-r). So if you are ok with a 'small amount of random variation to the location of each point', then `+geom_jitter` is a useful way of handling overplotting.

Comment: While this will work it will over plot the data and some of the points will show as a single value.  Better would be `+geom_jitter()`, `+geom_boxplot()` or `+geom_count()`