# Plotting multiple histograms on single plot to .pdf as a part of R batch script

Tags: r, plot

I am writing `R` scripts which play just a small role in a chain of commands I am executing from a terminal.  Basically, I do much of my data manipulation in a Python script and then pipe the output to my R script for plotting.  So, from the terminal I execute commands which look something like `$python whatever.py | R CMD BATCH do_some_plotting.R`.  This workflow has been working well for me so far, though I have now reached a point where I want to overlay multiple histograms on the same plot, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557042/129475) to another user's question on Stackoverflow.

Inside my R script, my plotting code looks like this:

```
pdf("my_output.pdf")
plot(hist(d$original,breaks="FD",prob=TRUE), col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4),xlim=c(0,4000),main="original - This plot is in beta")
plot(hist(d$minus_thirty_minutes,breaks="FD",prob=TRUE), col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4),add=T,xlim=c(0,4000),main="minus_thirty_minutes - This plot is in beta")
```

Notably, I am using `add=T`, which is presumably meant to specify that the second plot should be overlaid on top of the first.  When my script has finished, the result I am getting is *not* two histograms overlaid on top of each other, but rather a 3-page PDF whose 3 individual plots contain the titles:

i) *Histogram of `d$original`*
ii) *original - This plot is in beta*
iii) *Histogram of `d$minus_thirty_minutes`*

So there's two points here I'm looking to clarify.  Firstly, even if the plots weren't overlaid, I would expect just a 2-page PDF, not a 3-page PDF.  Can someone explain why I am getting a 3-page PDF?  Secondly, is there a correction I can make here somewhere to get just the two histograms plotted, and both of them on the same plot (i.e. 1-page PDF)?

The other Stackoverflow question/answer I linked to in the first paragraph did mention that alpha-blending isn't supported on all devices, and so I'm curious whether this has anything to do with it.  Either way, it would be good to know if there is a `R`-based solution to my problem or whether I'm going to have to pipe my data into a different language/plotting engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `hist` plots by default, returning invisibly a histogram object that can be plotted. So calling `plot(hist(..))` plots the histogram twice (two pages in your `pdf`), using `add=T` in the second call means that a third, but not fourth plot is created. You can set `plot = FALSE`, or not wrap the calls to `hist` within `plot()`.

To get this to work as a single page pdf (using the example from [How to plot two histograms together in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r/3557042#3557042)

```
set.seed(42)
p1 <- hist(rnorm(500,4), plot=  FALSE)                     # centered at 4
p2 <- hist(rnorm(500,6), plot = FALSE)    
                                             # centered at 6
pdf('foo.pdf')
plot( p1, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4), xlim=c(0,10))  # first histogram
plot( p2, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), xlim=c(0,10), add=T)

dev.off()
```