# How do I insert one more column in my Histogram and plot it on Y axis

Tags: r, csv

I want to plot Voters_2009 and Voters_2014 both in my histogram so that I can compare both of them. 
My Data is

`S.No     PC_Name          Voters_2009      Voters_2014
1          Bastar           564742           769913
2        Bilaspur           770089          1090457
3            Durg           905900          1258342
4  Janjgir-Champa           737608          1073347
5          Kanker           742076          1016943
6           Korba           745617          1052720
7      Mahasamund           776337          1131209
8         Raigarh           935750          1246186
9          Raipur           741969          1250845
10    Rajnandgaon           830578          1178296
11        Sarguja           805197          1187321`

```
DATA<-read.csv("CHATTISGARH FOR GEOJSON.csv")
ggplot(DATA,aes(x=PC_Name,y=Voters_2009))+geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

I am only able to plot Voters_2009 or Voters 2014. How do plot them simultaneously?

Comment: Please don't post data (or code) as images, post in `dput` format. Edit the question with the output of `dput(DATA)`, please.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Can you help me here. What is the use of dput? I have to copy paste my data in code format right?

Comment: Yes, that is the prefered way. Like this we can simply copy&paste to a session to create the data set.

Comment: Do you want an histogram or a bar plot?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Any of them will work

Comment: Is a 3D-histogram what you are looking for?

Comment: @David No sir I just need any graph or something to compare them. 2d graph will work.

Comment: So you want a histogram that represents both variables simultaneously? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638788/histogram-of-two-variables-in-r

Comment: @David yes David the one Rui barradas showed. Do you have any alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard trick is to [reshape the data from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) first, then plot grouping by a `variable` aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)

DATA_long <- reshape2::melt(DATA, id.vars = c("PC_Name", "S.No"))

ggplot(DATA_long, aes(PC_Name, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**Edit.**

If the graph is too full of bars, it may become unreadable. Facetting is a way of solving this problem. When the graph is divided into facets, the `fill` argument no longer tells which year is which.

```
ggplot(DATA_long, aes(PC_Name, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
DATA <-
structure(list(S.No = 1:11, PC_Name = structure(1:11, .Label = c("Bastar", 
"Bilaspur", "Durg", "Janjgir-Champa", "Kanker", "Korba", "Mahasamund", 
"Raigarh", "Raipur", "Rajnandgaon", "Sarguja"), class = "factor"), 
    Voters_2009 = c(564742L, 770089L, 905900L, 737608L, 742076L, 
    745617L, 776337L, 935750L, 741969L, 830578L, 805197L), Voters_2014 = c(769913L, 
    1090457L, 1258342L, 1073347L, 1016943L, 1052720L, 1131209L, 
    1246186L, 1250845L, 1178296L, 1187321L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: How do I change my whole data?

Comment: `{library(ggplot)
DATA_long <- reshape2::melt(DATA2, id.vars = c("PC_Name", "S.No"))

ggplot(DATA_long, aes(PC_Name, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))`

Comment: I changed my data frame but it returns me the same graph why?

Comment: It ran. But I have a new problem. There is a big bar I am not able to find out why http://prntscr.com/o9zcmo. I have now computed graph for my whole data.

Comment: Try to see which value is greater than, say, 2500000. And given the graph, maybe it's better to facet by years, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ggplot(DATA,aes(x=PC_Name,y=Voters_2009))+geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

try

```
ggplot(DATA,aes(x=PC_Name))+
     geom_histogram(aes(y=Voters_2009, color = 'red'), stat="identity") +
     geom_histogram(aes(y=Voters_2014, color = 'blue'), stat="identity")
```