# How to add frequency & percentage on the same histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram, frequency, percentage

Consider the following data set.

```
x <- c(2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,7,7,8,8,9,10,10,1,1,0,2,3,3,5,6)
hist(x, nclass=10)
```

I want to have a histogram where the x-axis indicates the intervals & the y-axis on the left represents the frequency. **In addition to this, I need another y-axis on the right side of the histogram representing the percentage of the intervals on the same plot**. Even though the following graph is for two variables, more or less it looks like what I need (taken from [Histogram of two variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638788/histogram-of-two-variables-in-r)).

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a vertical axis to the right side with `axis(4,at = at)`, where `at` are points at which tick-marks are to be drawn. If you want the density values of your histogram as tick-marks, call `axis(4, at = hist(x,nclass=10)$density)`.