# Histogram/bar chart containing two variables in bar

Tags: r, bar-chart, data-visualization

I want to make a [histogram](/questions/tagged/histogram) / bar chart that looks similar to the plot below:

[image: Click here]

I have the following code

```
d1 <- read.table("Session_data_TU2010AND15.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
d <- d1[,c("IncHouseh","HousehNumcars")]
```

The first variable `IncHouseh` is the income of different households. These should be shown in intervals on the x-axis, while `HousehNumcars` (the number of cars in household) should be the percentage shown in the bar for each interval.

The data **d** looks like this, however with more than 20000 rows:

```
      IncHouseh HousehNumcars
1           800             2
2           384             2
4           638             1
5           580             2
6           700             2
7           744             2
8           560             1
9           500             1
10          686             1
11          310             1
12          510             1
13          648             2
14          372             1
15          542             1
```

As I am new to [r](/questions/tagged/r), I find it very difficult to be able to illustrate something similar to the link provided above. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: After following massisenergy's code below (big thanks), I've managed to get this figure (which is correct):

[image]

Comment: Please provide `Session_data_TU2010AND15.csv`, so that others can try on your problem. No one here has any idea how it looks, except you!

Comment: Hi, I'm not allowed to upload the entire dataset, but I've provided some of the data points in the post.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184096/how-to-plot-multiple-stacked-histograms-together-in-r

Comment: Your graph is not a histogram. It looks more like a stacked relative frequency bar chart. So don't bother with the `hist` function. Look at `barplot` or `geom_bar` from the ggplot2 universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach, using the famous [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) for data manipulation and [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) for plotting the graphs. The pacakge `magrittr` is for pipe `%>%` construct.

**STEP1**

Read the data and structure it as a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) named `df`. Remember to use `stringsAsFactors = F` to make columns anything of type other than `factor` for easier data manipulation in the next steps.

```
library(dplyr); library(magrittr); library(ggplot2)
d1 <- read.table(text = "IncHouseh HousehNumcars
1           800             2
2           384             2
4           638             1
5           580             2
6           700             2
7           744             2
8           560             1
9           500             1
10          686             1
11          310             1
12          510             1
13          648             2
14          372             1
15          542             1", header =T)
df <- data.frame(d1, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**STEP2**

Use `mutate` (to add new columns suitable for plotting), `case_when` (to make `if-else` construct)

```
df <- df %>% mutate(x_labels = case_when(IncHouseh <= 100 & IncHouseh > 0 ~ "under100",
                                      IncHouseh <= 200 & IncHouseh > 100 ~ "100-200",
                                      IncHouseh <= 300 & IncHouseh > 200 ~ "200-300",
                                      IncHouseh <= 400 & IncHouseh > 300 ~ "300-400",
                                      IncHouseh <= 500 & IncHouseh > 400 ~ "400-500",
                                      IncHouseh <= 600 & IncHouseh > 500 ~ "500-600",
                                      IncHouseh <= 700 & IncHouseh > 600 ~ "600-700",
                                      IncHouseh <= 800 & IncHouseh > 700 ~ "700-800",
                                      IncHouseh <= 900 & IncHouseh > 800 ~ "800-900",
                                      IncHouseh <= 1000 & IncHouseh > 900 ~ "900-1000"))
df <- df %>% group_by(x_labels) %>% mutate(Probability = (HousehNumcars/sum(HousehNumcars)
                                           *100), Cars = as.factor(HousehNumcars))
```

**STEP3**

Plotting!

```
plot <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x_labels, y = Probability, fill = Cars)) + geom_col()
#some codes for beautification, but not necessary
plot + ylab("Probability or number of cars (%)") + xlab("Range of income") + 
ggtitle("Number of cars according to houshold income") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Goal: To make the grouping in a custom way for the fill variable `Cars`. THe idea is same: using `case_when`.

```
df_cars <- df %>% group_by(x_labels) %>% mutate(Probability = (HousehNumcars/
                                                sum(HousehNumcars)*100), Cars = 
                                       case_when(HousehNumcars == 1 ~ "1",
                                                 HousehNumcars >= 2 ~ "2+"))

#Plotting in the same way:
plot <- df_cars %>% ggplot(aes(x = x_labels, y = Probability, fill = Cars)) + geom_col()
plot + ylab("Probability or number of cars (%)") + xlab("Range of income") + 
ggtitle("Number of cars according to houshold income") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this helped a lot, so thank you for the code. However, something seems to go wrong with my car grouping because i have missing values (NA) in some of the rows. And also the maximum number of cars is 12, but for some reason 20 is also shown as a group. I've included the figure in the post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, it would help if I get to see some more of the data (& more importantly **more representative**). Can you take about `~30` rows from your data & post it? 15 is too less for this purpose I guess & also it only contains 1/2 cars. Need something that spans in the whole spectrum. Maybe it's because of this `NA` problem. Did you use `dput()` to take the example data that you gave here? If not, please use that. Please check this: [Example of using `dput()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput)

Comment: The values pretty much look the same, the only difference is that there are some missing values. But it was quite easily fixable by using the na.omit function. Btw I've updated my post above with the correct figure. The only thing I'd like to change about it is that I can get a group that covers 6+ cars instead of 6,7,8,9,10 as they are not that representative individually

Comment: Okay, glad to help. It's easy, using the `case_when`, in the same way. I just showed it for two cars, as I don't have more in the dataset.

Comment: Also, can you please upvote and accept the answer to mark that the problem is solved or it's helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You could first use `cut` to categorize the income data.

```
dat$IncHouseh.c=cut(dat$IncHouseh, seq(1e3, 5e3, 1e3), 
                    labels=c("10k-20k", "20k-30k", "30k-40k", "40k-50k"))
```

Then second, for the aggregation of percentage of number of cars you could use `prop.table(table(x)))` in a `tapply`.

```
agg <- do.call(rbind, with(t(dat), tapply(HousehNumcars, IncHouseh.c, FUN=function(x)
  prop.table(table(x)))))
```

Third, plot it!

```
op <- par(mar=c(5, 5, 4, 6), xpd=TRUE)                   ## expand outer margins
b <- barplot(agg, xaxt="n", col=2:5,                     ## assign position output to `b`
             xlab="Income", ylab="Probability", main="Cars in households")
mtext(rownames(agg), 1, 1, at=b)                         ## use `b` for label positioning
legend(5, 1, title="cars", col=5:2, pch=15, legend=3:0)  ## legend
par(op)
```

Note, that `dat` needs to be `t`ransposed.

## Result

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(IncHouseh=sample(1e3:5e3, 2e3, replace=T),
                  HousehNumcars=sample(0:3, 2e3, replace=TRUE))
```