# X axis edit for stacked histogram

Tags: r, stacked-bar-chart

I'm looking to sort a stacked graph as demonstrated here: [How to plot multiple stacked histograms together in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184096/how-to-plot-multiple-stacked-histograms-together-in-r)

However I need the x axis not to be 'value' with numbers, but instead have groups like 'car' 'van' 'bike', with the stacked plots occuring for each group. I'm not great at R yet and I can't work out how to edit it to do what I need. Explanations to solutions so I can learn and improve would also be really appreciated. Thanks

example input:
[image]

Output plot would have 'car', 'van', 'bike' on the x axis, 'count' on y axis, the stack on each group being made up of the 'red', 'blue', 'yellow' counts

I think I may have found the answer here:https://r-charts.com/part-whole/stacked-bar-graph/

If no ones solves it before I've had a go at the above link I may sort an answer myself, will see how things go.

Comment: Hi Giles. Can you please share a sample of your data using dput() and show the code you have so far for the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the last row of your dataset actually refers to the name of the column, you may need to lengthen your data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  "color" = c("red", "blue", "yellow"),
  "car" = c(6,2,2),
  "van" = c(1,4,4),
  "bike" = c(8,1,1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -color,
               names_to = "name",
               values_to = "value")

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = color)) +  
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

[image]