# Plotting two different distribution functions in R. Getting axis withing positive range of values

Tags: r, plot, histogram, probability-density

I was following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542115/3483997 approach in order to get 2 histograms (with different populations) integrated in the same data-frame.

`ROS_SPITFIRE <- data.frame(length = rnorm(100, 0.76406353, 0.500970292))
ROS_FARSITE <- data.frame(length = rnorm(398, 3.48366834170854,2.19050069588744))`

`#Now, combine your two dataframes into one.  First make a new column in each.
ROS_SPITFIRE$veg <- 'ROS_SPITFIRE'
ROS_FARSITE$veg <- 'ROS_FARSITE'`

`#and combine into your new data frame vegLengths
vegLengths <- rbind(ROS_SPITFIRE, ROS_FARSITE)`

`#now make your lovely plot
ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.3) 
ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.3)`

`ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, aes(y = ..density..), position = 'identity')
ggplot = ggplot + xlim((0,15))`

My problem popped up when I´ve created the new column in each data-frame. It generates negative values, hence my final distribution plots have negative values on the X-axes. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thx

Comment: You are creating your variable length from a normal distribution, which can there take on negative values. Thus your histogram will also contain these values

Comment: ahá, I guess I used it wrong since my data do not follow a normal distribution. is there anything equivalent to rnorm for NO normal cases?

Comment: try `sample(seq(.1, 1, by = .1), 100, replace = T)`  You can also decide what the probability of each instance in the `prob = ` in `sample`

Comment: You also don't have to supplement your dataframes - you could overlay the two using the data argument in geom_histogram so: `ggplot(ROS_SPITFIRE, aes(length, y = ..density..)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, fill = "spitfire", position = 'identity')+  geom_histogram(data=ROS_FARSITE, fill="farsite",alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')`

Comment: See also `?Distributions` for a list of distributions from which random numbers can be generated.

Comment: Nice @jbaums, I wasn't familiar with this one

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers! I tried your code @Steph Locke, but looks like R doesn't like it. I got "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric"

Comment: hmm .. I had to change the fill to be inside an aes, but it works `ROS_SPITFIRE <- data.frame(length = rnorm(100, 0.76406353, 0.500970292))
ROS_FARSITE <- data.frame(length = rnorm(398, 3.48366834170854,2.19050069588744))

ggplot(ROS_SPITFIRE, aes(length, y = ..density..,fill="spitfire")) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5,  position = 'identity')+ 
  geom_histogram(data=ROS_FARSITE, aes(fill="farsite"),alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')` http://imgur.com/XgXp4Fr

Comment: awesome, thanks @Steph Locke. I am still struggling with the negative values.

Comment: If you need to stick with the specific `mean`s and `sd`s used but exclude any negative values you can filter the datasets e.g. `ROS_SPITFIRE[ROS_SPITFIRE$length>0,]` or do limits on the chart e.g. `xlim(0,12)`.  If you can amend the distribution you can pick distributions or values that do not result in negative values

Comment: It is a pity because I cannot vote you up guys. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to stick with the specific `mean`s and `sd`s used but exclude any negative values you can filter the datasets e.g. `ROS_SPITFIRE[ROS_SPITFIRE$length>0,]` or do limits on the chart e.g. `xlim(0,12)`.

If you can amend the distribution you can pick distributions or values that do not result in negative values.  @Dave and @jbaum provide guidance like using `sample(seq(.1, 1, by = .1), 100, replace = T)` or evaluating other distribution options for going down this route.

You can also cut out some steps by going straight to charting and provide a limit:

```
ggplot(ROS_SPITFIRE, aes(length, y = ..density..,fill="spitfire")) + 
geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5,  position = 'identity')+ 
geom_histogram(data=ROS_FARSITE, aes(fill="farsite"), 
                 alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')+
xlim(0,12)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I am here again. I was wrong since the begining. What I have to plot is basically 2 different datasets in only one histogram based on counts  per pixel. The number of pixeles are different in each dataset. How can I plot a normal histogram in ggplot2 without density distribution involved? Many thanks before hand

Comment: You should be able to use geom_bar(). If you need more info,  I would suggest a new SO question

Comment: I think I could sort it out. For instance I´ve included NA to the shortest dataset. Afterwards just plotted histograms following the structure:                                                                                          qplot(V3, data=dsf, geom='histogram',xlab="m/min",main="ROS",fill=I('#FF9999'),alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_histogram(aes(V8), data=dsf, fill='#56B3E9', alpha = 0.5). Thanks by the way!