# ggplot plot error in R

Tags: r, syntax, plot, ggplot2

I am tryong to use `ggplot` in my data, but i get this error:

`##Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = .Primitive("length"), fill = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 3L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 245`

I am trying this command: `ggplot(all, aes(length, fill = NLABfather)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)`

Adaptaded from this topic [How to plot two histograms together in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r) (choosed aswer)

My `all` dataframe look like that:

`value  NLABfather

0.13    NE001362
0.17    NE001361
0.05    NE001378
-0.12   NE001359
-0.14   NE001379
0.13    NE001380
-0.46   NE001379
-0.46   NE001359
-0.68   NE001394
0.28    NE001391
0.84    NE001394
-0.43   NE001393
-0.18   NE001707
-0.47   NE001380
0.10    NE001362
-0.10   NE001381
0.08    NE001711
-1.15   NE001707
0.07    NE003322
-0.12   NE001394
0.19    NE001358
-0.61   NE001360
-0.12   NE001362
0.07    NE001394
0.10    NE001386
-0.53   NE001380
0.05    NE001380
-0.43   NE001362
-0.10   NE001395
-0.20   NE001389`

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data frame column is called `value` but you've put `length` in your function call.

```
 ggplot(all, aes(value, fill = NLABfather)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

produces something.