# How to create mirrored histograms

Tags: r, plot

I would like present propensity score matching stats on 2 groups (unmatched in BW, matched in color) and would like to use mirrored histograms like the following

[image]

Is it possible to overlay 4 different histograms in base R? Is there any package providing this functionality?

The x-axis is [0,1] bounded (it is a probability) and the BW columns are always bigger or equal to the colored columns (that is there cannot be BW columns "behind" the colored columns).

Image from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22244556

Comment: You can overlay base graphics with `par(new=TRUE)`. That's a start. And [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3557042/3005513) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. ´plot.histogram()´ also supports add=T. The tricky part is the "negative" histograms.

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure `ggplot` has some way to do it...

Comment: I am wondering if there is a more primitive way to plot the bars directly from the hist() object. Then it could be possible to plot the "negative" histogram.

Comment: In case my answer was not clear, I added a function that shows how one would take the approach I illustrated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like the following. You would want to pre-calculate the `hist` objects to get the correct ylim values, then use `axis` and `mtext` or `title` to properly label your graph.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)

plot.new()
plot.window(ylim = c(-40, 40), xlim = range(x))
p <- list(axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "")
par(new = TRUE)  
do.call(hist, c(list(x = x, ylim = c(-40, 40)), p))
par(new = TRUE)
do.call(hist, c(list(x = x, ylim = c(40, -40)), p))
axis(side = 2, 
     at = pretty(par()$usr[3:4]), 
     labels = abs(pretty(par()$usr[3:4])))
axis(side = 1)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
## Create some fake data
set.seed(1234)
d <- rnorm(250, 0, 1)
e <- rnorm(250, 1, 1)
f <- rlnorm(100, 0, .2)
g <- rlnorm(100, 1, .2)

## Function for plotting
multhist <- function(..., bin.width, col, dir, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
                     main = NULL) {

  vals <- list(...)
  vrng <- range(vals)

  brks <- seq(vrng[1] - abs(vrng[1]*0.1), 
              vrng[2] + abs(vrng[2]*0.1), 
              by = bin.width)

  yrng <- max(sapply(lapply(vals, hist, breaks = brks), "[[", "counts"))
  yrng <- 1.2*c(-1*yrng, yrng)

  plot.new()
  plot.window(ylim = yrng, xlim = vrng)

  addhist <- function(x, col, dir) {
    par(new = TRUE)  
    hist(x = x, ylim = dir*yrng, col = col, xlab = "", ylab = "", 
         main = "", axes = FALSE, breaks = brks)
  }

  mapply(addhist, x = vals, col = col, dir = dir)

  py <- pretty(yrng)
  py <- py[py >= yrng[1] & py <= yrng[2]]
  axis(side = 2, at = py, labels = abs(py))
  axis(side = 1)
  title(main = main, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)

}
```

You can give the function numeric vectors, as well as vectors for the corresponding colors and directions (1 or -1). I did not do the formal checking on the lengths of vals, col, and dir, but it is pretty straight forward.

```
## Use the function
multhist(d, e, f, g, bin.width = 0.5, 
         col = c("white", "white", "lightgreen", "darkgreen"), 
         dir = c(1, -1, 1, -1), xlab = "xlabel", ylab = "ylabel", 
         main = "title")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use base `barplot` twice, you just need to compute negative values for the down plot e.g. :

```
upvalues <- data.frame(Green=c(0,10,90,140,30, 20),White=c(70,50,30,20,5, 0))
downvalues <- data.frame(Green=c(-80,-70,-10,-60,-10,-10),White=c(0,-100,-60,-5,-15, -10))

# barplot accept only matrices
up <- t(as.matrix(upvalues))
down <- t(as.matrix(downvalues))

# empty plot to make room for everything
yspace <- 1.2 # it means 20% of space for the inside labels
plot(x=c(0,max(ncol(up))),
     y=c(min(colSums(down))*yspace ,max(colSums(up))*yspace), 
     type='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
a <- barplot(up,col=c('green','white'),space=0,add=T)
b <- barplot(down,col=c('darkgreen','white'),space=0,add=T,axes=F)

axis(side=1,at=seq.int(0,by=ncol(up)/10,length.out=11),
     labels=seq.int(0,by=10,length.out=11))
title(xlab = 'x label', ylab='y label', main = 'Title')
mtext('UP',line=-1,side=3,col='green')
mtext('DOWN',line=-1,side=1,col='darkgreen')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get it to work with different for different lengths of Green and  White vectors in both upvalues and downvalues? Perhaps get it to use a hist object for cosistency?

Comment: This example starts from predefined and aligned bar values. If you preprocess your input (having different lengths) maybe using hist objects, you can arrive to this format and then use the posted code.

Comment: Using this approach would create invalid x-values. ie. using a categorical plotting function for continuous data is not a safe/accurate approach.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on that @dayne

Comment: With this approach the x-values end up getting arbitrarily added. `barplot` is intended to graph frequencies by category (not by a continuous value).

Comment: Maybe it' me but actually, I don't see the difference with the histogram approach. I mean, when you calculate the histograms you get positions and heights of the "bars", so you basically obtain categorical data and you can use this approach...

Comment: @digEmAll The difference, in my mind, is that you cannot specify the location of the bars in `barplot` -- only the width and the spacing.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. Well, yes you can't specify the position but actually, since I assume the OP wants equally spaced bars, once you know the number of bars you want to divide the 0-100 range, you can easily calculate the heights and you don't need any x-position at all, since barplot will do the work for you. Yeah, it's maybe more complicated than your approach for continuous data, but since the OP hasn't provided any input I just recreated a plot with similar appearance ;)