# Propensity score distribution using mirrored histograms in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram, graphing

I want to create a mirrored histogram as seen in the sample chart below. A brief description: x axis is a continuous variable (propensity score, goes from 0 to 1) and y axis is count of individuals. The upper portion needs to show distribution of propensity score among treated and the lower portion, that of untreated. In addition, I want to show what proportion of patients in each treatment group were matched.

Sample chart:

[image]

This question was previously asked on this forum. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928712/how-to-create-mirrored-histograms)

The solution provided was great, however, it defines the x-axis as a vector of variables that are used to declare treated, untreated, matched-treated, matched-untreated (variables d e f g in the macro). I want to define the x-axis as the propensity score but am unable to find a way to modify the #multhist macro that this researcher created.

Please advise. Thank you for your time!