# r program grouping 3 histograms into one grouped histogram

Tags: r

I have created three different histograms,

- hist(decreased$Group.1),
- hist(increasd$Group.1) and
- hist(unchanged$Group.1)

Is there any way to combine these three histograms into one grouped histogram with different colors? Do we have to use ggplot for it or is there simpler way?

Comment: With lables for three different histograms possibly

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r

Comment: Use "ggplot" instead hist function, first. And bind your data, using "rbind".