# R a layered histogram with one layer for two vectors

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, histogram, bar-chart

```
combined <- read.table(text="seed_mass thatch_mass
 1        62         109
 2        53         120
 3        51          94
 4        43          61
 5        65          72", header=TRUE)
```

How can I make a layered histogram of mass with one layer for `seed_mass` and `thatch_mass`?

I tried to use ggplot but it wasn't working.

Comment: could you post a sample of your sees_mass and thatch_mass data in R statements and also an example graph? If you are talking about overlapping histograms, there are a few articles [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/overlapping-histogram-in-r/) is one of them..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Kevin: Despite my editting efforts it still not a good question. You did not include any code and the phrase "not working" is impossibly vague.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin, as the comments mention, you haven't provided any code in your question so I'm not entirely sure about what you are trying to do. Also, the phrase "layered histogram" is vague. If your goal is to create two histograms on the same plot then I would suggest looking [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/overlapping-histogram-in-r/) for how to do it in basic R and looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r) for how to do it using the ggplot2 package.