# R waterfall histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I need to plot the change in the distribution of comparable categories in different time-periods and show the change between them. I know I could [overlay histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r) with ggplot, but I was thinking to replicate a chart of similar style to this (coming from [here](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/page/5/)):

[image]

I am pretty sure there was an R package to create this type of plots, unfortunately, I can't find it anymore and I don't know any other name for the chart than waterfall plot. Maybe someone knows the package?

Thanks!

Comment: [`ggridges`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/index.html)

Comment: perfect, thanks! You can post it as an answer, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: This is really cool, thanks for pointing out such a cool visualization.