# How to plot two overlappling histograms like this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

The data is

|  | y0 | y1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M | 100 | 200 |
| F | 50 | 250 |

How to plot the histogram like this? Note that M and F do not block each other, so this is not the case in [How to plot two histograms together in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r). Thanks in advance.

[image: his]

Comment: Please provide the data with `dput`.

Comment: How exactly is your data stored? Is that a data.frame? It's better to share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) such as a `dput()`. Also, these would not be considered histograms. Histograms are a way to estimate the density function for a continuous random variable. What you've shown is just a stacked bar chart.

Comment: This is not a histogram, this is a barplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert your data to long format with `pivot_longer()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c("y0","y1"))

ggplot(data = df_long) +
  geom_col(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = sex)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("M" = "blue", "F" = "darkorange")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]
data:

```
df <- data.frame(sex = c("M","F"),
           y0 = c(100,50),
           y1 = c(200,250))
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I modify name to something like 'count' in <geom_col(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = sex)) ? It reports Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found. But name is also not defined in above code?

Comment: `pivot_longer()` created the field name `name`. Take a look at `View(df_long)` to confirm. To change the name in the data.frame you could use `names(df_long) <- c("sex", "count", "value")`, add the argument `names_to = "Count"` to `pivot_longer()`, or to change the x-axis label, you could use `+ xlab("Count")` in your ggplot function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_df <- tribble(~ sex, ~ y0, ~ y1,
                 "M", 100, 200,
                 "F", 50, 250)
my_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is like `df` below:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~V1,  ~y0,  ~y1,
  "M", 100L, 200L,
  "F",  50L, 250L
)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-V1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = V1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Which gives:

[image]